# Mathematical words outside of mathematics

Tags: soft-question, terminology, sociology-of-math

We've all heard expressions like "We need to factor this into the equation," where mathematical words have broader meanings than strictly mathematical. I'd like to develop a collection of such usages.  Of course, there's "grows exponentially" for just about any rapid growth, and "the rate has accelerated" not really meaning the third derivative.  Also, there's Friedman's cool usage of "orthogonal" at the Supreme Court (https://www.librarything.com/topic/193156).  Here's my two-part question: is there already list of such usages, somewhere? Can you contribute some examples?

Comment: This gives me an opportunity to ask, does anyone use the word "modulo" as a synonym for "ignoring" or "with disregard to."  At some point, I convinced myself this was a usage of this term outside of mathematics, and a rather useful one, though I have yet to uncover it being used in this way outside of a mathematical context.

Comment: On matheducators.stackexchange, there is a compiled list, although meant at a more elementary level. At some point a link will be provided.  Gerhard "Still Going Link Lite Presently" Paseman, 2019.12.20.

Comment: @AndySanders I've certainly seen that usage of "modulo" in CS/programming contexts, but of course that's only _just_ outside of mathematics.

Comment: @AndySanders : I use it that way too, but I must confess I've never heard anyone who didn't know some fair amount of maths use it

Comment: Related but almost the opposite, MESE: [Examples of Mathematical Slang](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/10348/511).

Comment: Perhaps "canonical": Meaning the most basic form (as opposed to according to canon law).

Comment: I've seen "matrix" [used in many contexts](https://www.google.com/search?q=matrix+literature) (not just for the movies), and "parallel" is used in [grammar/editing contexts](https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/mechanics/parallel_structure.html).

Comment: I'm often entertained by the way non-mathematicians use the phrase "existence proof" with its exact opposite meaning, ie. for a construction.

Comment: I would not say that "existence proof" is "the exact opposite meaning" of "proof by explicit construction".

Comment: For "modulo", the OED entry provides the following non-mathematical example: 1992   Stud. Eng. Lit.: Eng. Number (Tokyo) 161   The Navajo underlying structure is identical, modulo word order, to the one found in all the languages studied in Ch. 3.

Comment: I nominate "exponential" as what may be the most misused term.

Comment: Oh. Until now I actually thought that “orthogonal” *was* in common English usage.

Comment: How about "tangent" (as in "go off on a ...") and "tangential"?

Comment: My wife used to think it was funny that I used the word "nontrivial" so much, but now she does it too.

Comment: One of the most abused words in the media is "epicenter" meaning simply center.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy, I even saw misuse of "exponential" on MathOverflow, as in "this generalization is exponentially more powerful than the original statement," although I don't recall the exact wording.

Comment: @MichaelRenardy As far as I can tell, exponential can only *mean* $y'=ky$. Ain’t it great that we get to clear this up for (and only for) calculus students?

Comment: "Cusp" and "inflection point" are very common in US media.

Comment: @AndySanders “Modulo” $=$ “up to”, I would say both in and out of math.

Comment: "smooth operator"?

Comment: How about the famed journalistic 'angle'?

Comment: To differentiate tea (=re-brew).

Comment: Macquarie University has the slogan (or logo, or catchphrase, or whatever), $${\rm(you)}^{\rm us}$$ Rumor has it that the original suggestion was $(1)^{\rm us}$ until someone pointed out that $1$ to any power is still $1$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, what does [it](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348781/mathematical-words-outside-of-mathematics#comment873822_348781) mean?  I can guess “you power us”, but “1 power us”?

Comment: Sounds like a quite English-centered discussion, or rather chat. Little to do with mathematical research.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko "Epicenter" is from geology, not mathematics: it is the point on the earth's surface directly above the location of an earthquake.

Comment: @Robert Israel: or a point above which a nuclear explosion occurs:-) I suppose this is the reason it penetrated to the media.

Comment: @LSp it's meant to be read as "you to the power of us" and to convey the idea the we, the University, help you to be more powerful, or something.

Answer (score 5):

I've often wondered whether whoever created Delta Airlines' slogan
"Delta means change" had some mathematical training . . .

Comment: Physics, probably—hopefully there’s an aeronautics specialist somewhere in the organisational structure ....

Answer (score 4):

French intellectuals of a certain period made ***à la limite*** into a widespread idiom (or verbal tic) meaning, not just “borderline” or “in a pinch” as dictionaries say, but the taking of an argument to some sort of paroxystic or naked extreme. Random examples: from Philippe Sollers, *Vérité de Barthes*,

> Myth is everywhere, it irradiates everything; in the limit, it talks to itself alone in our heads.

Or Jacques Andrieu, *Psychologie de Mao Tsé-toung*,

> One can even say, in the limit, that only non-specialists can manage specialists.

Comment: Perhaps "at the end" would be an appropriate translation?

Comment: @AsafKaragila Yes, or “ultimately” — it’s about prime and ultimate ratios, and the ghosts of departed sanity.

Comment: I have no reason to believe that "à la limite" comes from the mathematical meaning.

Answer (score 2):

The mathematical word **parameter** has entered general English.  And its meaning has migrated, so that "parameter" now often simply means "a boundary or limit".

Comment: *parameter* gets confused with *perimeter* in much general usage.

Comment: The usage note in the American Heritage Dictionary is interesting on this one. It does not mention confusion with "perimeter," so I don't really think that's a major cause of this usage. More likely the interpretation of a parameter as an external constraint on the system. https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=parameter&submit.x=0&submit.y=0

Answer (score 2):

French has an expression "c'est epsilon" meaning something like
"it's negligible".  [French 
wiktionary](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/epsilon) says this sense is "par extension" from the mathematical usage.

There's also [lambda](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/lambda)
"(Éthologie) Un membre considéré comme le plus ordinaire d’un ensemble",
which might have a mathematical origin.

Answer (score 0):

A few more examples: infinite wealth, countless visits, uncountable advantages, success a function of hard work, appeal to the lowest common denominator, Venn diagram of circle A plus circle B.

Comment: Is it the same meaning of ‘denominator’?  I’ve never really understood.